# Make user as Default contributor for all Blog Posts

Tags: author

I need to get a different requirement, where a particular user need to set as default contributor.

I'm not sure whether wordpress actually makes a user default. But for now i need to make a user as default contributor to all the posts, posted on the Blog.

Question is : How to set a user as default Contributor?

Comment: What do you mean by "default contributor"? When someone registers you want them to be set to "contributor" role?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to change the Author for existing posts.

If this is the case, in your Admin screen, go to

> Posts | All Posts

and place a checkmark next to whichever posts you want to reassign the Author. Then, near the top, in the ***Bulk Actions*** dropdown, select ***Edit*** and click ***Apply***. You'll see something similar to the image below. Select the appropriate Author from the dropdown shown.

[image]